# Why is my button undefined in my test?

Tags: reactjs, testing, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

My test:

```
  describe('button component', () => {
    it('should toggle off when clicked', () => {
      let component;
      component = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Search />);
      let searchbtn = ReactTestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(component, 'button');
      ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(searchbtn);
      console.log(searchbtn, 'search button***'); //UNDEFINED
      expect(searchbtn.calledOnce).to.equal(false);
    })
  });
```

This is my search component:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search">
        <button className="searchButton" onClick={this.handleSearch}>{this.state.on ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Do I need to spy on it or mock it? or is there a better way to test buttons in react?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have added `enzyme` tag I will answer using `enzyme`.

It can be tested very easily via shallow rendering -

```
const searchWrapper = shallow(<Search />);
const button = searchWrapper.find('button').first();
```

When you simulate click event on button the `onClick` handler provided via `onClick` prop which is `handleSearch` in your case will be called.

So if you are setting some state based on the `onClick` function call corresponding ui changes based on the state changes can be compared or checked if changes were reflecting correctly in the dom.

or

if you just want to check if method was called or not by using a fake method of similar name -

```
const onButtonClick = sinon.spy();
expect(onButtonClick.calledOnce).to.equal(false);
button.setProps({ onClick:onButtonClick});
button.simulate('click');
expect(onButtonClick.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
```

Comment: @Theworm You can use the selectors available in enzyme(similar to css selectors- via id, class name, elements types, props) e.g I have used const button = searchWrapper.find('button').first();

Comment: ok cool. .first() seems painful if you have many buttons but I'll look at the docs. thanks :)

Comment: You can select specific target button as well.